# Validating input with cin

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>

int main()
{
    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    while (std::cin.fail() || m <= 0) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin >> m;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is supposed to prompt for an input until a positive integer is entered. But even after entering a positive integer it keeps prompting for an input.
For example, lets say I have the input as

```
abc
c4
-3
1
2
.
.
```

So in principle the moment I enter `1`, the execution should be transferred out of the loop. But it keeps prompting for an input and looks like an infinite loop.

After looking around for a while, I modified it as

```
cin >> m;
while (cin.fail() || m <= 0) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    cin >> m;
}
```

As desired, entering a positive number terminates the loop.
I didn't get it. Why the new line character is stuck in the input buffer?
Suppose I have this

```
int a , b;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
```

When my input is

```
1
2
```

It correctly sets `a` to `1` and `b` to `2`, instead of setting `b` to `\n`.
Why is the behaviour different in the two cases?

Comment: How would `b` get set to `\n`? `b` is an integer.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath variables have been defined. Sorry I forgot it

Comment: Don't "forget" it. Present your clear, concise and precise [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that **demonstrates the issue** so that we are not guessing/assuming at things that you may or may not have done.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then how in the very first code snippet, `m` is being set to `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that there's a stray newline, but that the entire input is still in the stream.

`cin >> m` fails immediately if it can't extract an integer.
It does not read the next "word" and see if it's an integer, and then stop after that "word" if it wasn't - the "read pointer" is left at the point of initial failure.

The `ignore` skips ahead to the end of the line and ignores everything up to that point.

To illustrate the difference, this program tries to read the input first as `int` and if that fails, reads the same input again as a `std::string` for use in the error message:

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    string s;
    while (!(cin >> n))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin >> s;
        cout << "That wasn't an int, it was " << s << endl;
    }
    cout << "This is an int: " << n << endl;
}
```

The solution you found with `ignore` is pretty much the "standard" solution.

Comment: That's what the `ignore` is for, no? Why extract the characters when you can skip over them? And how is this solution different from the OP's? At best, it is and you need to explain why. At worse, it isn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried to make it clearer that the code wasn't an alternative solution so much as an illustration. (The question is why the behaviour is different, not what the best solution is.)

Answer (score 0):

The newline will be eaten up when extraction succeeds (whether the extracted integer is positive or not).

It won't be eaten up when extraction fails.

Comment: So what exactly happens at `cin >> m` in the first code snippet.

Comment: I have no idea, because you did not **demonstrate the issue** showing your input. Why don't you simply step through the program in your debugger, examining the stream state and value of `m` at every step?

Comment: Let the input be `abc`

Comment: @ibrahim There is no positive integer in that input. Why would the program end? **Demonstrate the issue**. I won't tell you again.

Comment: @ibrahim5253: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Not sure why you're having trouble following instructions.

Comment: What an idiot I am! (didn't go through the instructions earlier) Is it fine now?

Comment: @ibrahim5253: Much! Now you've got it. Thanks.